# Datos sobre el idioma español. Cantidad de palabras

Tags: vocabulario, rae

En algun lugar leí que el diccionario de la academia española tiene alrededor de 95.000 entradas (palabras), y que una persona con una educación mediana maneja aproximadamente de 5.000 a 7.000 palabras en su vocabulario. ¿Alguien puede confirmar estos datos? ¿O comentar al respecto?

Comment: Creo que cinco o siete mil es un número bastante optimista. A lo sumo diría un par de millares.

Comment: Dice [este interesante artículo de la BBC](http://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias/2011/04/110330_palabras_ingles_lp.shtml) que 7500. Sin embargo, distintos artículos ([este de zona del escribidor](http://zonadelescribidor.blogspot.com.es/2008/12/cuntas-palabras-usamos-al-hablar-en.html), por ejemplo) dan los mismos números de 283 mil palabras, de las cuales usaríamos 300 --> _Una persona, en su vida cotidiana, utiliza unas 300 palabras; 500, si es culta. Un novelista bueno utiliza tres mil_.

Comment: Primero hay que definir «palabra».

Comment: Creo que es bastante más clasificar como *vocabulario* a esas *palabras*.

Comment: Cierro esta pregunta pues es demasiado amplia. Considera editarla para definir más claramente los conceptos sobre los cuales una respuesta pueda ser válida. Cuando lo hagas, puedes seleccionar "flag" para que procedamos a reabrir la pregunta. ¡Gracias!